# Python How to accept only certain words with user input

Tags: python, list, input, xbmc, kodi

Ok so The script is now working, Id like to thank all for the advice.

heres the final script

```
import smtplib 
import xbmc
import xbmcgui
import datetime

list = ("mary", "james", "tilly")

kb = xbmc.Keyboard('', 'Please type in your name to continue')
kb.doModal()
typedin = kb.getText()

if typedin.lower() in list:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    runtime = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

    content = xbmc.executebuiltin('kb.getText()')
    mailserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.mail.com",25)
    mailserver.ehlo()
    mailserver.starttls()
    mailserver.login('mail@somemail.com','somepwd')
    mailserver.sendmail('mail@somemail.com','mail@somemail.com',typedin + ' has run proggy ' + runtime)
    mailserver.close()
    xbmc.executebuiltin("Notification(An email has been sent, yada yada yada,()")
else:
    xbmc.executebuiltin("THE INPUTTED NAME, IS NOT VALID,()")
    xbmcgui.Dialog().ok(
    "Please try again - User name not correct",
    "The input yada yada",
    "yada yada",
    "yada yada")
```

So, just to let you know that im using live mail which works on port 25.
Tried and tested on both windows and linux and openelec. Working fine.

Comment: What do you want to happen when the user input is not in the list?

Comment: for the moment is just to exit out  using else: 
    xbmc.executebuiltin("Notification(Name is not in list, exiting,()")    xbmc.executebuiltin("ActivateWindow(10000,return)")

Comment: xbmc.executebuiltin("The Name you have used, was not in the list,()" is already on the bottom of the code, but not running if the names do not match.

Comment: I don't have those things installed so cant test it, but how about instead of the else an 'if tpyedin.lower() not in str1:'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something along the lines of an if statement? So only if one of these words are given, then do the rest, otherwise do not accept.

```
list = ["simon", "tom", "sarah", "peter", "jane"]
word = input()
if word.lower() in list:
    print('Ok')
    #continue with rest of program
else:
     print('No, sorry')
```

Comment: I'll have a go with that shortly and post back. thanks firefly

Answer (score 1):

The best to do in a situation where one wishes to grab input from a user is to do a while loop with a raw_input statement like:

```
word_list = ['simon', 'tom', 'sarah', 'peter', 'jane', 'sue']

def get_word():
    """returns the word that the user chooses"""
    print("Please choose a name from the following:")
    w_string = ""
    for w in word_list:
        w_string += w + ', '
    #print the word list without a comma at the end.
    print(w_string[:-1])

    while True:
        word = raw_input("\n> ") #use input("\n> ") for python3
        #If you wish to accept something like "SiMoN      " or "S Imon "
        #have the following line:
        word = word.lower().strip()
        if word in word_list:
            return word
        else:
            print("'%s' is not in the list of words. Please choose from the following:\n%s" % (word, w_string[:-1]))

word = get_word()
print(word)
```

Comment: I have edited the script showing the progress. 50% working now. More Info at the bottom of first post. Thanks for your help

Comment: xbmc.executebuiltin("The Name you have used, was not in the list,()" does not look right. I don't know why you're not using print, but what I think this should look like is: xbmc.executebuiltin("The Name you have used, was not in the list")

Comment: Pasted the final code. Thanks to all for the advice. Solved

Answer (score 0):

I the best option would me not to covert the list to string and check if the entered name is in the list like..

```
import smtplib
import xbmc
import xbmcgui
import datetime

nameList = ["simon", "tom", "sarah", "peter", "jane"]
kb = raw_input('Please type in your name to continue:')

if kb in nameList:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    runtime = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

    content = xbmc.executebuiltin('kb.getText()')
    mailserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.mail.com",25)
    mailserver.ehlo()
    mailserver.starttls()
    mailserver.login('mail@somemail.com','somepwd')
    mailserver.sendmail('mail@somemail.com','mail@somemail.com',typedin + 'has run keymail ' + runtime)
    mailserver.close()
else:
    print ("The Name %s, was not in the list")%kb
```

and dont use list and str as a variable names.